How to check if transaction is in mempool using Infura apis
I am trying to check if a pending transaction is still in the mem pool using infura api eth_getTransactionByHash or alternativly using JS web3js.eth.getTransaction(hash).
in both methods i am getting null value.
please advise how it can be done or if there is another way to get the information.

Dev Advocate at Chainstack here.
You have a couple of options depending on what you want to do.
Check if a transaction is still pending
If you have the hash, you can use eth_getTransactionByHash to fetch the transaction details, as you already mentioned in your question. This method returns a bunch of fields; two of the fields returned are the following:

blockHash — the block hash. Identifies the block in which the transaction was included. This field is null for transactions not yet included in a block.

blockNumber — the number of the block in which the transaction was included. This field is null for transactions that are not yet included in a block.


If the transaction is still pending and was not included in a block, these two fields will be null, so you can assume the transaction is still pending and in the mempool.
If the result is empty or null as a whole, the transaction was probably not broadcasted properly and does not exist.
Here is an example of how to implement it in web3.js:
const { Web3 } = require("web3");
const NODE_URL = "CHAINSTACK_NODE_URL";
const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);

async function getTransaction(transactionHash) {
    const transaction = await web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash);
    
    // Use a truthy check to handle both null and undefined
    if (!transaction.blockHash || !transaction.blockNumber) {
        console.log('Transaction is pending or not found.');
        // Optional: Handle the scenario (e.g., retry, log, notify)
    } else {
        // Transaction has been processed
        //console.log(transaction); // Optionally log the entire transaction
        const blockHash = transaction.blockHash;
        const blockNumber = transaction.blockNumber;
        console.log(`Block Hash: ${blockHash}, Block Number: ${blockNumber}`);
    }

    // Optional: Return transaction details or status based on your requirements
}

getTransaction("0xdea9446aa9c63a5428cd224e860369c15573a306685c86d2027d1a1e2a6e70fe");

Listen for pending transactions in real time
The second option is to listen for pending in real time using subscriptions and a WebSocket endpoint.
This will log the hashes of the pending transactions the node finds in the mempool. You can then add logic to inspect the transactions to see their effective state if you need to. Here is an example of how to listen for pending transactions in real-time with web3.js
const { Web3 } = require("web3");

const NODE_URL = "CHAINSTACK_WSS_URL"; // Ensure this is your WebSocket endpoint
const web3 = new Web3(NODE_URL);

async function subscribeToPendingTransactions() {
  try {
    // Subscribe to 'pendingTransactions' event
    const subscription = await web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions');

    console.log(`Subscription successful, Subscription ID: ${subscription.id}`);

    // Event listener for new pending transactions
    subscription.on('data', (transaction) => {
      console.log('New pending transaction:', transaction);
    });

    // Event listener for any errors during the subscription
    subscription.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('Subscription error:', error);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error subscribing to pending transactions: ${error}`);
  }
}

subscribeToPendingTransactions();


thanks a lot for your answer !
my issue is that eth_getTransactionByHash returned null object but the tx is present in etherScan as pending (probably it is not taken because low gas). it doesnt seems that there is an issue with the tx and that it not broadcasted.

Mmm, in that case, the transaction probably wasn't propagated to the node you are using, which can happen for various reasons. Does it always happen, or are these mostly isolated cases? I think this might be a good use case for using the fallback provider in ethers.js. TL;DR: it fetches data from various endpoints ( you could use different providers) and ensures all endpoints agree. I made a tutorial about it: https://docs.chainstack.com/docs/enhancing-blockchain-data-reliability-with-ethers-fallbackprovider
